# is race condition possible?

Tags: java, thread-safety

I am wrapping java mail transport class and calling my method to process the sending email has valid address.

**Transport Class**

```
 public class Transport  extends javax.mail.Transport {

private static final String  CLASSNAME = Transport.class.getName();

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CLASSNAME);


public Transport(Session session, URLName urlname) {
    super(session, urlname);
}

@Override
public void sendMessage(Message msg, Address[] addresses) throws MessagingException {
    Dispatcher.processMailSending(msg,addresses);
    send(msg,addresses);
}

public static void send(Message msg , Address[] addresses) throws MessagingException{
    Dispatcher.processMailSending(msg,addresses);
    javax.mail.Transport.send(msg,addresses);
}

public static void send(Message msg) throws MessagingException{
    Dispatcher.processMailSending(msg);
    javax.mail.Transport.send(msg);
}

}
```

**Dispatcher Class**

```
  public class Dispatcher{
       public static void processMailSending(Message msg , Address[] address){
           Validator v = new Validator();
           v.validate();
       }

       public static void processMailSending(Message msg) throws MessagingException{
           Validator v = new Validator();
           v.validate();
             //TOD: do validation
       }
  }

 class Validator{
      private Message msg;
      private Address[] address;

      public Validator(Message msg , Address address){
             this.msg = msg;
             this.address = address;
      }

      public void validate(){
          checkSpam(msg.getFrom());
      }
 }
```

I read oracle forum post. They said `Transport.send` is thread safe .

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1589778&tstart=2865 .

**My Question**

is `Dispatcher.processMailSending` thread safe?

I avoided using `syncrhonized` modifier in `processMailSending` . This method will be invoked frequently .

Please suggest your views .

Answer (score 0):

You've not provided any implementation for `Dispatcher.processMailSending` so it's impossible to say. It'll be thread-safe if there's no shared state in the `Dispatcher`. Note that by using `static` methods, you're immediately increasing the possibility of sharing state - can you instantiate a `Dispatcher` for each invocation ?

However the impact of any synchronisation will be massively outweighed by the time taken to send a mail to a mail server, and I think you're optimising prematurely. Make sure your code is thread-safe (using synchronisation or other higher-level solutions like `Executors`) and then worry about optimisations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is. This is because there is no shared, mutable state within `Dispatcher`. As long as you don't make use a static variable within `Dispatcher` that itself is not thread safe, then fine. Usage of threadsafe objects like AtomicInteger, ConcurrentHashMap, Vectors are fine.

Comment: Seems fine because the Validator class is created within the method stack.